# Convert from custom PyTorch model to TorchScript to load in C++

Tags: pytorch, torchscript

I have a custom model in PyTorch, something like:

```
class CustomModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    <some init>
  def forward(self, x):
    <some code>
    return <something>
  def custom_forward_for_inference(self, x):
    <some code>
    return <something>
```

Then I convert model using:

```
torch.jit.trace()
```

But after loading in C++ and run inference by `custom_forward_for_inference`:

```
at::Tensor output = loadedModule.custom_forward_for_inference(inputs).toTensor();
```

It raised : `no member named 'custom_forward_for_inference' in 'torch::jit::Module'

How can I script that custom method for inference in C++?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The prob is that `torch.jit.trace()` traces the forward pass, and does not work with other methods. However, PyTorch provides a fix for with `torch.jit.script()`, which allows the conversion of the entire model, including all its methods, to TorchScript.

Here's a pseudo type of way you can use `torch.jit.script()` using the code you provided above:

```py
class CustomModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
    # <some init>

  def forward(self, x):
    # <some code>
    return # <something>

  def custom_forward_for_inference(self, x):
    # <some code>
    return # <something>

# Create an instance of your model
model = CustomModel()

# Script the entire model, including all methods
scripted_model = torch.jit.script(model)

# Save the scripted model
scripted_model.save("custom_model.pt")
```

Once you've saved the scripted model, you can load it into C++:

```cpp
// Load the scripted model
torch::jit::script::Module loadedModule = torch::jit::load("custom_model.pt");

// You can now call your custom method
at::Tensor output = loadedModule.forward("custom_forward_for_inference", inputs).toTensor();
```

The `torch.jit.script()` converts your model to TorchScript. Which is better than tracing, but you have to write said model in Python, so it compiles to TorchScript.